Sort changes type of array
Let's say I have the following type:
interface MyType { 
    myProperty: [a: string[], b: string[]] 
}

and now I want to create an array out of that type:
const array1: MyType[] = [
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
];

If I try to sort that array:
const array2: MyType[] = [
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
].sort((a,b) => a.myProperty[0].length - b.myProperty[0].length);

I get an error:
Type '{ myProperty: string[][]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'MyType[]'.

I tried various workarounds:

Array initialization with sort (lambda)
const array2: MyType[] = [
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
].sort((a,b) => a.myProperty[0].length - b.myProperty[0].length);

Value doesn't have correct type

Array initialization with sort (function)
const array3: MyType[] = [
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
].sort(compareMyType);
function compareMyType(a: MyType, b: MyType) { 
    return a.myProperty[0].length - b.myProperty[0].length; 
}

Sort function doesn't have correct type and value doesn't have correct type

Casting to MyType[]:
const array4: MyType[] = ([
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
] as MyType[]).sort(compareMyType);
const array5: MyType[] = ([
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: 5},
] as MyType[]).sort(compareMyType);

Casting supresses errors which can cause runtime errors

Sorting already initialized array
const array1: MyType[] = [

    const array2: MyType[] = [
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
];

const array6: MyType[] = array1.sort(compareMyType);

No errors.


Why is this working, while the other attempts are not (compiler or runtime errors)? Are there better/other workarounds?
Playground

"sort changes type of array" - no, the problem is that the assignment to MyType[] happens after the sort, so it has to go purely by the inferred type of the array literal (which is { myProperty: string[][]; }[]). As you already see, any of the ways that ensure the array is MyType[] before sorting work just fine (e.g. https://tsplay.dev/ND0kzN, ).

The stumbling block is that TypeScript's default behavior is to infer the type of an array literal as a plain array type and not a tuple.  TypeScript's contextual typing doesn't usually work through a function call, so while const arr: MyType[] = [⋯] will have the proper context for it to succeed, const arr: MyType[] = [⋯].sort(⋯) will not.
The best way to proceed here is probably to use the satisfies operator instead of a type assertion:
const arr: MyType[] = ([
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
] satisfies MyType[]).sort(compareMyType);

You can use satisfies to provide context for type inference without losing type safety.
Playground link to code

Thanks. I didn't know that keyword existed yet.

The issue is in the order in which TypeScript does the type checking and type inference. If you just split the assignment and sort into two separate commands everything works fine.
interface MyType { 
    myProperty: [a: string[], b: string[]] 
}

const array1: MyType[] = [
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
];

const array2: MyType[] = ([
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
])

array2.sort((a,b) => a.myProperty[0].length - b.myProperty[0].length);

Playground
Since the sort method sorts the array in-place this accomplishes what you were after.
The problem was that in your case you were calling the sort method on the array literal, so TS had to infer the type of your array literal independently from the type of the array2 variable that you specified, because the sort method needed the type information of what it was sorting. Only after it would attempt to assign the return of the sort array to the typed array2 variable and that's where the incompatibility occurred.
To see what TS inferred that literal to just assign it to an untyped variable:
const array3 = ([
    {myProperty: [["Hello", "World"], []]},
    {myProperty: [["Hello"], []]},
])
// const array3: { myProperty: string[][]; }[]

As you can see, the literal type was inferred to a simpler structure, the myProperty field was not a tuple, it was inferred just as a regular string array. But if you perform the assignment separately, as in my example, TS will do a more granular check on the literal and make sure it matches the requested type.
